# US citizen wanting to use American brokerages while living in Colombia SA

Tags: united-states

I am a USA citizen residing in Colombia.  I expect to be here beyond 183 days.  I was told by one popular USA brokerage that they can´t do business with me.  They made it extremely difficult to recover my money.   A second brokerage in USA said that because I live outside the US they can only offer me only a cash account which pretty much restricts me to two trades maximum per week.  They said that Colombia is on a restricted list. I like to day trade.

Are there any USA laws that make it illegal to offer me full services such as margin, use of brokerage offered debit cards and the 3 round trips in 5 days?  I am only talking $8000 at this time.

Comment: Why not keep a US address, and do business online?  I had no problems while living & working in Europe, though I only put money in my mutual fund accounts.